# My code generates a folder instead of a text file

Tags: c#

My code generates a folder, but I want a text file. I already tried to modify the path but it does not work:

```
try
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\" + "\\Funcionarios" + "\\Dados" + ".txt", true); //Abre o arquivo txt 
    sw.WriteLine(label1.Text + " " + data[0] + " " + label2.Text + " " + data[1] + " " + label3.Text + " " + data[2]); //Escreve no txt
    sw.Close(); //fecha o arquivo txt
}
catch
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\" + "\\Funcionarios" + "\\Dados" + ".txt"); //Cria um diretório
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\" + "\\Funcionarios" + "\\Dados" + ".txt", true); //Abre o arquivo txt
    sw.WriteLine(label1.Text + " " + data[0] + " " + label2.Text + " " + data[1] + " " + label3.Text + " " + data[2]); //Escreve no txt
    sw.Close(); //fecha o arquivo txt
}
```

Error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException:'C:\Funcionarios\Dados.txt'
```

Comment: If you don't want to create a directory, why are you using `Directory.CreateDirectory`? Did you look in the System.IO namespace documentation to see if there was something more relevant to creating a file?

Comment: You're telling CreateDirectory to create a directory named "c:\Funtionarios\Dados.txt". But that's the file that you want to put in the directory. Tell it to create the directory you want to create: `Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Funcionarios");` But first, go back and delete the subdirectory named "Dados.txt" that you created, so you can create the file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Test whether the directory exists before accessing the file, instead of running into an exception. This saves you from writing repetitive code. You are getting the exception because you are using the full file name, instead of just the intended directory part, to create the directory.

```
string path = @"C:\Funcionarios\Dados.txt";
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); // C:\Funcionarios

// Creates the directory unless it already exists.
Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

string text = $"{label1.Text} {data[0]} {label2.Text} {data[1]} {label3.Text} {data[2]}\r\n";
File.AppendAllText(path, text);
```

- There is no point in concatenating a string with `"C:\\" + "\\Funcionarios" + "\\Dados" + ".txt"`, this won't create a string that is any different from the simple string constant `"C:\\\\Funcionarios\\Dados.txt"`.
- Use a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) starting with `@`. This suppresses C#'s escape sequence processing and saves you from doubling the `\`.
- [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) stating with `$` simplifies string creation.
- The static method `File.AppendAllText` creates the file if does not already exist, opens it, appends the text and closes it with one simple method call. This is much easier than dealing with `StreamWriter`.

According to [Directory.CreateDirectory Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.8):

> **CreateDirectory(String)**
>   Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist.

Comment: You don't actually need to test for `Directory.Exists` since `Directory.CreateDirectory` only creates a directory if not present already.